# How to share an object in react.?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I use react with electron.
I have to share a client object all over the react components.
It has to store data when login function executed.
I did use "electron-store", however, that library didn't store data same as original.
Also redux and context did not working well...

Is there any other way to simply share object?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext ?

Comment: Actually, my code is written in class component...

Comment: here is an example with class-based components - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using [React Context](http://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). It is likely that you don't need any complex store libraries for just passing an object down.